# Django's permission management using native sql

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x

My Django program uses native mysql to do the query. There is no ORM. The back-end management system has sales staff and management staff. They see different interfaces. The administrator can see all the interfaces, while the sales staff can only see some of the interfaces What should I do? I am a newbie to python and have not been exposed to such problems. I need help very much, thanks!

Comment: The ORM doesn't really influence this question. You control access to different parts of the application primarily in views.

Comment: Do I need to set model permissions for different categories of people accessing different interfaces?

Answer (score 0):

in [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#permissions) you will find few ways to do what you need.

The easy method is with decorators. Suppose a simple def view:

```
from from django.contrib.auth.decorators import staff_member_required

@staff_member_required
def view_page(request, *args, **kargs):
  return render(request, "view.html", {})
```

Now, both admin (which has all the perms) and staff got access to view.html. A normal or anonymous user will get the "access denied page"

You can get the same goal in class views, with the PermissionRequiredMixin:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import PermissionRequiredMixin

class MyView(PermissionRequiredMixin, View):
   permission_required = 'is_staff'
```

or with some particular perm:

```
permission_required = 'AppLabel.can_dosomething'
```

Note that in this case, the user need the 'can_dosomething' perms for AppLabel.

But beware, the is_staff flag in User Django model give few perms like view the admin site, and another ones. If what you want is just give some perms but not a lots, you'll probably feel more confortable creating a group with that perms, and add your "staff users" there.

There are some more info in the link above

Comment: According to my understanding, does this method still require synchronous migration to use Model

Comment: Can I ask you why that program use a framework as django without ORM? Im feeling confuse, almost the entire django admin functionality use it. I Hope you find the solution.

Comment: Can I do just migrate synchronous auth_permission?